# Custom Named entity recognition

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

So i have task in front of me to make a custom ner model for the pharmaceutical industry where in i have a finite list of drugs and over 4000 text files from where NER is supposed to be done. I have also tried entity matching using spacy but it is showing some error. So now i plan on using SKlearn crfsuite but in order to do that my data needs to be in conll format and should be annotated.Would really appreciate if someone could guide me in annotating my text files! is there any way i can initiate automatic annotation on the text files using the drug list i have ? as it is a humongous effort for an individual to achieve the same manually.I also had a look at the question asked in the link mentioned below.
[NER model to recognize Indian names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073018/ner-model-to-recognize-indian-names)
But no one has actually addressed my question.Would really appreciate if someone could help me out

Spacy code:-

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span



class EntityMatcher(object):
    name = 'entity_matcher'

    def __init__(self, nlp, terms, label):
        patterns = [nlp(term) for term in terms]
        self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
        self.matcher.add(label, None, *patterns)

    def __call__(self, doc):
        matches = self.matcher(doc)
        spans = []
        for label, start, end in matches:
            span = Span(doc, start, end, label=label)
            spans.append(span)
        doc.ents = spans
        return doc

data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\xyz\pname.xlsx')
ld=list(set(data['Product']))
nlp = spacy.load('en')

entity_matcher = EntityMatcher(nlp, ld, 'DRUG')
nlp.add_pipe(entity_matcher)
print(nlp.pipe_names)    

doc=nlp('Hi bnbbn, ope all is well.  In preparation for the bcbcb is there anything that BGTD requires specifically?  We had sent you the US centric Briefing Package to align with our previous discussion on having bkjnsd included in the Wave 1  IMOVAX POLIO submission plan. If you would like, we can set-up a BGTD specific meeting after the June 20th meeting to discuss any jk specific product questions you may have as the product mix is a bit different between countries.')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)

when i run my script, this is the error i  get :-

[T002] Pattern length (11) >= phrase_matcher.max_length (10). Length can be set on initialization, up to 10.
```

Comment: why the down vote? i will improve my question asking skills if the question is not clear.Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Updated with the spacy code i used.

Comment: I have not seen your data yet. But I assume it is in the form of text. For NER, Extract a text from the data use string matching and label the drug in the text as D and others as O, Now convert this to embedding with D and O as labels. Now use some ML techniques. If this is not clear I  will try to answer it instead of commenting.