# pronounceable names or words in R

Tags: r, nlp, package

I  have a large database containing two fields useful for the question. ben_id (beneficiary id) and ben_name (beneficiary name).  I have given the task to analyse this large database for inconsistencies/anomalies/ other irregularities.

A hit and trial has shown presence of these records in data (obviously ids are illustrative here)..

```
ben_id      ben_name
1           asdfg
2           zxcvb
3           ZXCV
4           ZXCVB
5           zzzzz
6           Fffdd
```

My problem is to find out all such cases where the name possibility is too low due to low pronounceability of the name given.  It may indicate presence of wrong entries, errors, etc.

Is there any external package in R where I can put a pronounceable score of each ben_name in another column.

I know my question is a bit awkward, but please help if you can.

Comment: Would it be easier to compare each ben_name to a list of assorted names (e.g. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3201/files/NAMES.TXT) and flag those that aren't on the list for manual examination? 'Pronounceability' is a difficult task and you will likely need to provide more details if you want someone to help you

Comment: As many times happens, in @jared_mamrot link my first name is not present, the closest is *Ruiz*. I don't believe the problem is well posed.

Comment: Names are a hard problem. You can't assume anything about them. You can't assume how many names a person has. You can't assume that you will be able to pronounce every name (some languages are pretty weird from a Euro/America-centric perspective). "asdfg" or "Fffdd" might be perfectly valid names in some languages (you could still flag them as anomalies, but be careful with the next step).

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think that a "pronouncability" function or algorithm exists. There are commercial products out there tackling the name analysis problem and they are based on data sets. My advice would be to search the web for census data. A good start could be the data set available on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/us-baby-names

Comment: @Roland.  I agree fully.  I only want to flag results of my analysis for further verification may be through actual field verification.  Still, in my country (India) I don't think that there is rare of rarest possibility of someone having `zzzz` name or `asdfg` name.  My instinct and experience (not in R) says these are bogus records and are created to siphon off funds.

Comment: @MichaelSebald, there is some info i came across on internet, but is beyond my perception. https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W15-5921.pdf
Would be helpful if any package is available based on algorithm discussed therein

Comment: Before proceeding further, you should match against an official name database. Depending on how many records don't match this, you'll have to consider next steps. For example, in Germany, we have databases of first (given) names. You could even use phone books as a name corpus.

Comment: @AnilGoyal, thank you for the interesting article! I guess the question is what your use case is. Are you looking for pronouncable words or for correct (person) names? Two examples: 'Ingrid' is a proper German first name whereas 'Inigiridi' is perfectly pronouncable but by no means a proper (German) first name. The topic is also very much a cultural thing: the Slavic first name 'Mieczysław' for example is not very much pronouncable for me (being a German).

Comment: @RuiBarradas - good point - my first suggestion is useless for non-english names. Another approach that might suit is to build your own named entity recognition classifier based on your own criteria (i.e. common Indian names from twitter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189677/12957340) or use something like this resource: http://au-kbc.org/nlp/NER-FIRE2013/

Comment: @MichaelSebald My use case is to only flag a certain number of records which have a very high probability of fake/bogus entries, for further field examination through actual surveys, etc.  Moreover, In India we normally (with reasonably high probability) tend to name keeping in view its pronounceability.  Like in my example i stated that I already detected entries such as `asdfg` which are nothing else but a keyboard combination.  If such a package exists, it will filter out these kind of entries.

Comment: @jared_mamrot, thanks for sharing the links.  I will respond after going through these